# Python remove brackets and String quotation marks from array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, file-handling

```
myArray = []
textFile = open("file.txt")
lines = textFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    myArray.append(line.split(" "))
print (myArray)
```

This code outputs

```
[['a\n'], ['b\n'], ['c\n'], ['d']]
```

What would I need to do to make it output

```
a, b, c, d
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding a `list` to your result (`split` returns a list). Moreover, specifying "space" for split character isn't the best choice, because it doesn't remove linefeed, carriage return, double spaces which create an empty element.

You could do this using a list comprehension, splitting the items without argument (so the `\n` naturally goes away)

```
with open("file.txt") as lines:
    myArray = [x for line in lines for x in line.split()]
```

(note the `with` block so file is closed as soon as exited, and the double loop to "flatten" the list of lists into a single list: can handle more than 1 element in a line)

then, either you print the representation of the array

```
print (myArray)
```

to get:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or you generate a joined string using comma+space

```
print(", ".join(myArray))
```

result:

```
 a, b, c, d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
myArray = [[v.strip() for v in x] for x in myArray]
```

This will remove all the formatting characters.

If you do not want each character to be in its own array, you could then do:

```
myArray = [v[0] for v in myArray]
```

To print, then 'print(', '.join(myArray))

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should be using strip() (trim whitespace) rather than split() (which generates a list of chunks of string.

```
myArray.append(line.strip())
```

Then 'print(myArray)' will generate:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

To print 'a, b, c, d' you can use join():

```
print(', '.join(myArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
import re
arr = [['a\n'], ['b\n'], ['c\n'], ['d']]
arr = ( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in arr ))
arr = arr.replace('\\n', '')
new = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+', '', arr)
print(new)
```

Result:

```
a,b,c,d
```